# C++ compiler for python supported C++11 (MinGW and MSVC) (also cl.exe fatal error)

Tags: python, c++11, gcc, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to install python package from `setup.py`.
Actually this one: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText
I use python 3.6 (anaconda, built in in Visual Studio 2017)

I have Visual Studio 2017 and install MinGW:

```
C:\MinGW\bin>gcc --version
gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
```

Then I use:

```
python setup.py install
```

and get next error message:

> error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'

I found this mean I need to use C++11 features. Ok. But how?
I tried to change file `distutils.cfg` in my python directory to use next compilers:

```
mingw32
msvc
```

But for `msvc` get another error:

> error C2039: 'to_string': is not a member of 'std'

---

I found some information, to add `-std=c++11` to use some c++11 features, but **I can't understand where and how to use it! Do I need write it in python shell after install? Or in distutils.cfg?** I tried both and got:

> error: option -s not recognized ---> for python
>
> error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'nt' with
>   'msvc -std=c++11' compiler ---> for distutils.cfg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much time later I found a solution.
The problem was I didn't install MSVC correctly and (IMPORTANT) didn't add this to the PATH variables.
So the right sequencing:

1. Install next tools using Visual Studio Installer (you can get free version here: [microsoft_official](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/downloads/)):

   - MSBuild
   - Basic components Visual Studio C++
   - VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools
   - Visual C++ instruments for CMake
   - C++/CLI support
   - SDK for Windows 10 (10.0.17134.0)
   - Visual C++ instruments for CMake and Linux
   - Toolbox v14.13 and 14.11 for VC++ 2017 15.4/15.6
     Slightly difficulty is here: sometimes packages' names change from version to version of Visual Studio Installer and I have non-English version, so I translated their names manually. Perhaps You don't need all of them but this set is worked for me.
2. Now you have MSVC compiler, we need to tell python to use it: add the cl.exe path to PATH variables in Windows (usually it locates here):
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin`

This solved problems for tons of python packages when using Windows. But you need to install big application for this (several GBs).